# Dynamin upload path with AJAX file uploader

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im using http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ on my site. I would like to know if theres a way to get the upload path from a textbox or similar.

Index.php:

```
<script>
   function createUploader(){
       var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
           //  pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
           element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
          // path to server-side upload script. In our case server/php.php
          action: 'server/php.php'
       });
   }
   window.onload = createUploader;
```

php.php:

```
...
$result = $uploader->handleUpload('../../uploads/');
...
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily, like this:

jQuery:

```
var uploadLoc = "/my/upload/path";
uploader.setParams({ action: "server/php.php?p="+uploadLoc });
```

PHP:

```
...
$result = $uploader->handleUpload($_GET["p"]);
...
```

Comment: When i upload something, i never see the get-variable. Have i missed something?

Comment: Change what you already have to `action: 'server/php.php?p=/my/upload/path'` and in your PHP file make the changes I indicated in my answer.

Comment: When im trying `var path = $("#path").val();
   
           var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
              
               element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
            
     
              action: 'server/php.php?p=' . path
           });` i get an upload error, any idea why?

Comment: When i hardcode in the path, like ../../uploads/. it works, but when i type it in my textfield it doesnt work.. I call the createUploader() function after the path has been set

Comment: Haha, it doesn't work because this is not PHP and you have to use the '+' sign. :D